# Google Maps Creating two markers and a line between them

Tags: google-maps

I am wondering how I can create two markers on a google map (upon click) and have a line drawn between them.  Ideally both markers would be draggable after they are initially dropped and the line would readjust accordingly.

Comment: Have you read the API Documentation, have you tried anything??  Show some code..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this example, though is already deprecated it might help you to get an idea
http://maps.forum.nu/gm_flight_path.html